# comma separator instead of | in emeditor find, filter windows permanently

Tags: emeditor

The multiple text separator in em editor is **|** in find, filter windows.
i don't want to use **|** separator? actually i want to use **,** in place of |. i didn't find any setting for this purpose.
is it possible to set the multiple text separator as **,** instead of **|** in em editor **find, filter windows** for multiple text (regular expression )separation permanently. where is such setting available in configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This "alternation" operator ("OR" operator) `|` is not an EmEditor setting, but a part of regular expression syntax. You can't change this character `|` as far as I know.

Comment: can i force emeditor to take , as | whenever i type ,. may be using the macro or keyboard mapping , to | permanently.

Comment: using the autohotkey script i am able to achieve my requirement. #IfWinActive, ahk_exe EmEditor.exe

,::
SendInput |
return
#IfWinActive   can we write similar code in emeditor also?

Comment: I am not familiar with autohotkey script, and I don't know how this is related to your first question. Please clarify your question, and focus one question at a time.

Comment: using autohotkey script i am able to force , typed  to be read as |  always in emeditor. i am not asking you to write autohot key script. this is related to my first question only. i am asking you whether you can give any emeditor script /macro/setting to force , typed to be read as |. i am concentrating on my first question only . for every question  you are simply writing " focus one question at a time"

Comment: You didn't mention autohotkey in your first question. Please re-rewrite your question and post it again as a new question. You should include all information in the first main question, not in a comment. I won't be able to answer your question because I am not familiar with autohotkey, but some other users might have answers.